# How to customize vertical panel in cinnamon menu?

Tags: customization, cinnamon

I want to edit highlighted area: for example, change Firefox with chromium or remove any item. Menu editor can change only right part of menu, changing default application has no effect on this panel.

[image]

Comment: Similar question here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77732/15760 and tagged linux-mint

Comment: Something wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area is known as the `Favorites` menu.

In order to re-arrange the applications it's as simple as dragging and dropping them into whatever order you want. (As you would do to icons on the desktop.)

To remove a certain application simply drag and drop it into the main application list and it will be removed from the favorites section.

To add an application to the favorites section you need to right-click the desired application in the application list and choose the option `Add to favorites`. (As per the image.)

[image]